# Is there any wrong in my query for Cumilative window frame function?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**-- Created table**

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(NAME VARCHAR(15),GENDER VARCHAR(10),SALARY INT);
```

**-- Inserted values**

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES
('AJAY','M',1000),('SURYA','M',3000),('RITHU','F',4000),('KARTHIK','M',2000),('SAMANTHA','F',10000),('MSD','M',10000);
```

-- **Cumulative Window Function**

```
SELECT 
  NAME, 
  GENDER, 
  SALARY, 
  AVG(SALARY) OVER(ORDER BY SALARY ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS AVG_SAL, 
  COUNT(SALARY) OVER(ORDER BY SALARY ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS COUNT_SAL, 
  SUM(SALARY) OVER(ORDER BY SALARY ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS SUM_SAL 
FROM 
  EMPLOYEE 
ORDER BY 
  SALARY;
```

**-- Answer for my query**

[image]

The rows which I marked in the answer image`(1,2)(10000,20000)` should be `(2,1)(20000,10000)`

Comment: What's the problem? That the last 2 rows should be in a different order? But you are `ORDER BY SALARY`, which is the same for both?

Comment: Please explain the logic for your preferred ordering.  It is nowhere in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, since both Salaries are equal, you will need to define another column in the ORDER BY in order to get further order:

E.g.

`ORDER BY SALARY, COUNT_SAL DESC`

or

`ORDER BY SALARY, SUM_SAL DESC`

Both of them will give the following **output**:

```
NAME     GENDER SALARY AVG_SAL COUNT_SAL SUM_SAL
-------- ------ ------ ------- --------- -------
AJAY     M      1000   5000    6         30000
KARTHIK  M      2000   5800    5         29000
SURYA    M      3000   6750    4         27000
RITHU    F      4000   8000    3         24000
MSD      M      10000  10000   2         20000
SAMANTHA F      10000  10000   1         10000
```

Bear in mind that this will work in the example, but may not work with more duplicate salaries. You will need to find different columns to apply this logic.